# How to display an image based on temperature range or weather conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, openweathermap

I want to display images based on the temperature or weather conditions that OpenWeatherMap API provides. So far I've gotten it to show me a basic weather report but I can't figure out how to create an IF statement based on the provided data. Can anyone show me how I would go about creating a IF statement in combination with a range in temperature or based of the current weather conditions? I have posted my current script below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Weersinformatie API Bergschenhoek</title>
  <style>
html, body { 
 font-size: 20px; 
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #d70080; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 line-height: 2;
}
 
h1 {
 color:#f4f4f4;
}
 
div {
       position: absolute;
       top: 30%;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
}
   
ul {
 list-style:none;
 color: #fff;
}
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class=ïmg" id="data-img">
  <section>
    <h1>Huidige weer in Bergschenhoek</h1>
    
    <ul>
      <li><b>Weersconditie:</b> <span id="data-current"></span></li>
      <li><b>Temperatuur:</b> <span id="data-temp"></span>&deg;</li>
      <li><b>Luchtvochtigheid:</b> <span id="data-humidity"></span>%</li>
      <li><b>Windsterkte:</b> <span id="data-wind"></span> km/u</li>
    </ul>
  </section></div>
  <script>
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bergschenhoek&units=metric&APPID=d2e5fd3c23340d44d09af919eb51e52a",function(data){ 

            console.log(data);
            $("#data-current").text(data.weather[0].description);
            $("#data-temp").text(data.main.temp);
            $("#data-humidity").text(data.main.humidity);
            $("#data-wind").text(data.wind.speed);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to check?

Comment: It's for a dynamic outdoor ledscreen campaign. I would like to check OpenWeatherMap for the current temperature (or the weather condition) and show an advertisement (image) based on the data that is extracted from the API. So far I'm struggling on setting up IF statements to show certain images based of of the temperature data from OpenWeatherMap.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this is to first create an array of ranges, like so:

```
let tempRanges = [{low: 0, high: 10, image: '0-10.png'}, {low: 10, high: 20, image: '10-20.png'}, {low: 20, high: 30, image: '20-30.png'}];
```

I'm working of an assumption that your temperature ranges are not intersecting. Values used here are obviously just an example.

Next create a function that finds a matching range based on the specified temperature:

```
function findRangeByTemperature(temp) {
   return tempRanges.find(range => {
      return temp >= range.low && temp < range.high;
   });
}
```

Note that the lower range bound is inclusive and the upper range bound is not. So given ranges 0-10 and 10-20 and input temperature of 10, it's going to fall into the 10-20 range. This is done to prevent ambiguity when matching ranges.

Finally, in your code it will look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weersinformatie API Bergschenhoek</title>
    <style>
    html,
    body {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #d70080;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 2;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #f4f4f4;
    }

    div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class=ïmg" id="data-img">
        <section>
            <h1>Huidige weer in Bergschenhoek</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Weersconditie:</b> <span id="data-current"></span></li>
                <li><b>Temperatuur:</b> <span id="data-temp"></span>&deg;</li>
                <li><b>Luchtvochtigheid:</b> <span id="data-humidity"></span>%</li>
                <li><b>Windsterkte:</b> <span id="data-wind"></span> km/u</li>
            </ul>
            <img id="data-temp-img" />
        </section>
    </div>
    <script>

    let tempRanges = [{low: 0, high: 10, image: '0-10.png'}, {low: 10, high: 20, image: '10-20.png'}, {low: 20, high: 30, image: '20-30.png'}];

    function findRangeByTemperature(temp) {
       return tempRanges.find(range => {
          return temp >= range.low && temp < range.high;
       });
    }

    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bergschenhoek&units=metric&APPID=d2e5fd3c23340d44d09af919eb51e52a", function(data) {

        console.log(data);
        $("#data-current").text(data.weather[0].description);
        $("#data-temp").text(data.main.temp);
        $("#data-humidity").text(data.main.humidity);
        $("#data-wind").text(data.wind.speed);

        let range = findRangeByTemperature(data.main.temp);
        // range was found
        if(range) {
            // display range.image
            $("#data-temp-img").attr("src", range.image);
        }
        else {
            // range was not found, maybe show a default image?
        }
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error);
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This should work. The pre specified ranges would be perfect for easy implementation. Thanks a lot!! I will continue working on this tomorrow but your example shows promise.

Comment: Hi abadalyan, How would you go about displaying the right range-image given that the images are called 0-10.png, 10-20.png and 20-30.png and placed in the same folder as the HTML document?

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. It's working very nice. Just out of curiosity for some future exploration, would it be possible to use this same approach to show specific HTML files instead of images?

Comment: Yes, the overall approach stays the same. After finding the right range you can load and display HTML file contents, using for instance [jQuery.load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You could also keep hidden HTML elements on the same page and toggle their visibility based on range.